# Does std::forward_list support manual re-pointing?

Tags: c++, linked-list, std, forward-list

The following is such a trivial question that it probably has been asked before, however, I wasn't able to find an answer through search.

What I am trying to do is use std::forward_list to implement some of the exercises in "Cracking the Coding Interview" in C++. In my understanding, a linked list element contains a) data and b) a pointer to the next element. Some of the solutions require re-pointing the "next" pointer to another element, like this (Pseudo-Code)

```
node1.next = node1.next.next.next; // Effectively deletes 2 elements
```

However, I can't find any way to do this in the [forward_list documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/)? Am I missing something, or is it simply not possible?

I am perfectly happy if someone could point me to the correct question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do manual repointing in `std::forward_list`, because it hides all mechanics from you. This is why it was created!

Instead, you need to perform business operations on it. For example, to delete elements from the list, you need to call `erase_after()` - it even has the overload to delete two consequtive nodes in one shot.

Comment: You were created to prevent OP from doing manual repointing in `std::forward_list`? :P

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, I'd love to believe I have a purpose in life :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

What you're missing is the fact that the standard library containers partially hide the details of how they're implemented. The internal "next" pointers are an implementation detail not visible to you. (This is not so relevant for `std::forward_list`, which is almost certainly a singly linked list, but it is relevant for, say, `std::set`: you can't access the internal red/black colour field, and anyway a different implementation could use a different kind of self-balancing tree.)

The correct way to delete the next 2 elements is to simply use the public API of `std::forward_list`.

```
my_list.erase_after(iterator_to_node);
my_list.erase_after(iterator_to_node);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to work through the public API or you risk leaking memory; `forward_list` doesn't provide direct access to the pointer, but between [`erase_after`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/erase_after/) and [`splice_after`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/splice_after/) you can enlist `forward_list`'s help to accomplish the same task with equal efficiency.

If you had an iterator `it` into the list `mylist`, you could perform the same logical two element deletion to remove the two subsequent elements with:

```
mylist.erase_after(it, std::next(it, 3));
```

Comment: @SergeyA At least it is easy to fix: `std::next(it, 3)`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, i am well aware of this.

Comment: @SergeyA: Ah, blech. Annoying that `forward_iterator` doesn't let you, you know, go forward in a straightforward manner. Fixed per @Revolver_Ocelot.

Comment: Well, it allows - just not in one shot. Basically, it is something to remind you that this operation is going to take some time :)